# Extreme noob query about interface

Tags: interface, go

With reference to [this code](https://github.com/codegangsta/martini/tree/1e4aeab7db2abca401ae3889129849e8613e220d#mapping-values-to-interfaces)

How to interpret this code?

`(*http.ResponseWriter)(nil)`

Is it type assertion or something else? I dont understand.

Also can interfaces have pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `nil` pointer.

`nil` pointers have a type, in this case it's `*http.ResponseWriter`.

Edit to answer question in comment section:

The reason for doing this is that [`inject`](https://github.com/codegangsta/inject) (Martini's dependency injector) maps an interface type to an implementation of that interface through [`MapTo`](https://github.com/codegangsta/inject/blob/master/inject.go#L106).

As it's really only interested in the interface's *type* (as second argument), a `nil` pointer is enough.

Comment: Thanks but what is the use of it? Can you show me some reference? I will be glad. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I saw its reflect.Type as key and they are sending a nil pointer of certain interface type. Pretty weird though. Looks like its how you store reflect.Type type. Or its some reflection black magic.

Comment: Its accepting an object nil of type *http.ResponseWriter. Yes got it. Thanks